# Sub level categories on wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to display secondary level categories using Wordpress. The problem right now is that I can only display top level categories or I can display the child of the main categories. However, I wish to display the main category and then the sub category only.

Currently I have the following code:

```
$category_data = get_queried_object();
$args = array('parent'=>$category_data->term_id);
$categories = get_categories($args);
```

The problem with this is that after it displays the second category, it stops displaying categories because it assumes that I have another category under the second category. I only want it to display the secondary category.

Comment: you could do two loops in your template - one that spits out the main cat, and follow it with one that only spits out the child cat.

Comment: you can also combine it with this function : https://wpmayor.com/how-to-check-if-category-is-a-subcategory/ which can check if the category you are on, is a child category